# Java ArrayList Class

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I started this code and I don't know how to finish it. I need to make the class and test driver for a collection of SalesPeople and their data. I created the salespeople class and constructor. i created the accessors and mutators. I need help combing into this into an arrayList class for my test driver. PLEASE HELP (:

```
import java.util.*;
 public class salesPerson {

   //salesPerson fields
   private int salespersonID;
   private String salespersonName;
   private String productType;
   private int unitsSold = 0;
   private double unitPrice;

   //Constructor method
   public salesPerson(int salespersonID, String salespersonName, String productType, int unitsSold, double unitPrice)
   {
     this.salespersonID = salespersonID;
     this.salespersonName = salespersonName;
     this.productType = productType;
     this.unitsSold = unitsSold;
     this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
   }


   //Accessor for salesPerson
   public int getSalesPersonID(){
       return salespersonID;
    }

   public String getSalesPersonName(){
       return salespersonName;
   }

   public String getProductType(){
       return productType;
    }

   public int getUnitsSold(){
       return unitsSold;
    }

   public double getUnitPrice(){
       return unitPrice;
    }

   public double getTotalSold(){
        return unitsSold * unitPrice;
    }

   //Mutoators for salesPerson
   public void setSalesPersonID(int salespersonID){
       this.salespersonID = salespersonID;
   }

   public void setSalesPersonName(String salespersonName) {
       this.salespersonName = salespersonName;
    }

   public void setProductType(String productType){
       this.productType = productType;
    }

   public void setUnitsSold(int unitsSold){
       this.unitsSold += unitsSold;
    }

   public void setUnitProce(double unitPrice){
       this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<salesPerson> salesPeople = new ArrayList<salesPerson>();
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean newRecord = true;
        int salespersonID;
        String salespersonName;
        String productType;
        int unitsSold = 0;
        double unitPrice;

        do{
            System.out.println("Please enter the Salesperson Inoformation.");
            System.out.print("Salesperson ID: ");
            salespersonID = userInput.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Salesperson Name: ");
            salespersonName = userInput.next();
            System.out.print("Product Type: ");
            productType = userInput.next();
            System.out.print("Units Sold: ");
            unitsSold = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Unit Price: ");
            unitPrice = userInput.nextDouble();



            System.out.print("Would you like to enter more data?(y/n)");
            String askNew = userInput.next();
            newRecord = (askNew.toLowerCase().equals("y")) ? true : false;

        }while(newRecord == true);

    }

 }
```

Comment: create object of the class `salesPerson` and [add](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add_index.htm) it to the arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already created a variable called **salesPeople**.
After taking all the inputs from user create a new object of **SalesPerson** and add to the **salesPeople** at the end in while loop.
Check the Below code for more clarity.

```
.....
SalesPerson tmp = new SalesPerson(salespersonID, salespersonName, productType, unitsSold, unitPrice);
salesPeople.add(tmp);

}while (newRecord == true)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your do-while-loop after you have all the data. You need to create each SalesPerson after you have the data, otherwise the values (id, name...) will just be lost and overwritten in the next loop-iteration

```
salesPeople.add(new SalesPerson(salespersonID, salespersonName, productType, unitsSold, unitPrice));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the arraylist salesPeople takes objects of salesPerson you will first want to create an object of salesPerson and then add the salesPerson to the salesPeople arraylist.

```
salesPerson sp = new salesPerson(salespersonID, salespersonName, productType, unitsSold, unitPrice);
salesPeople.add(sp);
```

Put that at the end of your do while right before you ask them if you want to create a new salesPerson.

Answer (score 0):

add below 2 lines(creating sp object and adding it to list)  at the end of do that is before the line below

```
System.out.print("Would you like to enter more data?(y/n)");

SalesPerson sp = new SalesPerson(salespersonID, salespersonName, productType, unitsSold, unitPrice);
salesPeople.add(sp);
```